# In tabActivity, tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount() returns 1

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have a TabActivity with two tabs showing two lists. I used tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount() to change the tab indicator dynamically. But while starting the application getChildCount returns 1 instead of two.

please help me..

I'm attaching my code here..

```
 @Override
public void onTabChanged( String arg0 )
{
    if ( LIST1_TAB_TAG == tabHost.getCurrentTabTag() )
    {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
        iv.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.rupees));
        Log.v( "check", "onTabChanged :: ChildCount == " + tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount() );

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `getTabWidget().getTabCount()` and `getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think `getChildCount()` is a method inherited from `ViewGroup` class and has nothing to do with the number of tabs in the tab widget to loop through the tab views in a tab widget use

in the context of a tab activity

```
for (int tabIndex = 0 ; tabIndex < getTabWidget().getTabCount() ; tabIndex ++)
{
   View tab getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabIndex);
}
```

if a normal activity with a TabHost use

```
yourTabhostVariable.getTabWidget()
```